# Creating Association with condition using other association in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, associations, conditional-statements, cakephp-3.0, has-many

I'm building a cake php 3 app. My app model includes 3 Tables (amongst others):

- Structures
- MeasuringPoints
- DeviceTypes

where each Strcuture can have multiple MeasuringPoints:

```
// StrcuturesTable.php
...
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    ...

    $this->hasMany('MeasuringPoints', [
        'foreignKey' => 'structure_id'
    ]);
}
```

Further, each measuring point is of a certain device type:

```
// MeasuringPointsTable.php
...
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    ...
    $this->belongsTo('DeviceTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'device_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

What i'm lookong for, is how to create a 'SpecialMeasuringPoints' association in the Structure table.

Somewhat like:

```
// MeasuringPointsTable.php
...
    $this->hasMany('SpecialMeasuringPoints',[
            'className' => 'MeasuringPoints',
            'foreignKey' => 'structure_id',
            'conditions' => ['MeasuringPoints.DeviceTypes.id'=>1]
    ]);
```

As you may see, I want only those measuring points, whose associated device type has the id 1.
However, the previous association condition is not valid; and i have no clue how to correctly implement this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, that condition is invalid, for a number of reasons. First of all paths aren't supported at all, and even if they were, you already are in `MeasuringPoints`, respectively `SpecialMeasuringPoints`, so there would be no need to indicate that again.

While it would be possible to pass a condition like:

```
'DeviceTypes.id' => 1
```

That would require to alawys contain `DeviceTypes` when retrieving `SpecialMeasuringPoints`.

I would suggest to use a finder, that way you can easily include `DeviceTypes` and match against your required conditions. Something like:

```
$this->hasMany('SpecialMeasuringPoints',[
    'className' => 'MeasuringPoints',
    'foreignKey' => 'structure_id',
    'finder' => 'specialMeasuringPoints'
]);
```

In your `MeasuringPoints` class define the appropriate finder, for example using `matching()`, and you should be good:

```
public function findSpecialMeasuringPoints(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    return $query
        ->matching('DeviceTypes', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
            return $query
                ->where([
                    'DeviceTypes.id' => 1
                ]);
        });
}
```

Similar could be done via the `conditions` option when passing a callback, which however is less DRY:

```
$this->hasMany('SpecialMeasuringPoints',[
    'className' => 'MeasuringPoints',
    'foreignKey' => 'structure_id',
    'conditions' => function (
            \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
            \Cake\ORM\Query $query
        ) {
            $query
                ->matching('DeviceTypes', function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                    return $query
                        ->where([
                            'DeviceTypes.id' => 1
                        ]);

            return $exp;
        }
]);
```

It should be noted that in both cases you need to be aware that such constructs are not compatible with cascading/dependent deletes, so do not try to unlink/delete via such associations!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. Currently I have implemented a workaround for this, but i will definitely try it with a custom finder!